# 'Dream coming true' variations?

Tags: tenses

Need a present perfect continuous tense for the above sentence.

I thought: “dream being coming true”, still I wanted to describe the action in general.

Answer (score 0):

Present perfect continuous is formed using **has/have** + **been** + **present participle**. The correct tense is **has/have been coming**. E.g. "*My dreams have been coming true lately*."

Comment: Being and coming should not come together; it is like doing doing.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!